# naming columns and rows of an array (using 'dimnames =' argument in the syntax)

Tags: r

how can we assign names to rows and columns of a array in R. below is what i tried using.

```
a<- array(1:50,dim = c(25,2),dimnames = list("Col1","col2"))
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to specify the rownames and column names.  Below, we are assuming the rownames to be NULL and the column names as 'Col1' and 'Col2'

```
out <- array(1:50,dim = c(25,2), dimnames = list(NULL, c("Col1", "Col2")))
```

According to `?array`

> dimnames: either ‘NULL’ or the names for the dimensions.  This must a
>             list (or it will be ignored) with one component for each
>             dimension, either ‘NULL’ or a character vector of the length
>             given by ‘dim’ for that dimension.  The list can be named,
>             and the list names will be used as names for the dimensions.
>             If the list is shorter than the number of dimensions, it is
>             extended by ‘NULL’s to the length required.

Comment: also can you please help me with accessing these named columns of the array ?

Comment: @Karan.  It is just `out[, "Col1"]#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25`